# Unable to show Alert with ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript when placed in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

Actually,I need to show `Success Message` and after Clicking `OK`,It should `Redirect` me to another `Page`.
Upto Now,Everything works fine.But after placing `UpdatePanel`,the `Alert` is not Showing.

My Code :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Create Time Table", "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Time Table Created Successfully.'); window.location.href = 'create.aspx';</script>");
```

I tried with :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Create Time Table", "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Time Table Created Successfully.'); window.location.href = 'create.aspx';</script>",true);

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Create Time Table", "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Time Table Created Successfully.'); window.location.href = 'create.aspx';</script>",false);
```

But,none of these worked :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have update panel give update panel id and its type as below

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                UpdatePanelID,
                UpdatePanelID.GetType(), 
                "Create Time Table", 
                " alert('Time Table Created Successfully.'); window.location.href = 'create.aspx';",
                true);
```